# Swift Updates broke my dictionaries

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, xcode6

I use JSONObjectWithData to parse a JSON, and was using the following code to retrieve information:

```
fotos[0]!["foto"]!["thumb"]!
```

But now, after I updated Xcode, it's giving the following error: "Type Int does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'

I have to do the following to work:

```
let item_thumb = fotos[0] as NSDictionary
var url = item_thumb.objectForKey("foto")!.objectForKey("thumb")!
```

By the way, using item_thumb["foto"]! as I would use in other places, is also giving me an error: "Type String does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'"

Can you help me out why it isn't working anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
fotos[0]["foto"]!["thumb"]!
```

Because first one is array, not dictionary (0 is index, which is of type int, not a key, which is string ).

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, but as I said in the beginning, I'm not just declaring a simple Array with Dictionary, I'm parsing a JSON, that's whats giving me the error. See: http://swiftstub.com/54996322/

I'm fine with explicitly casting to NSDictionary, but as I said, this problem didn't happened in the first betas of swift, that's why I posted this question

Comment: @Paulo So this is actually very strange. What makes the compiler think that it is an Int?.. I don't know.